# Mysqli_stmt_num_rows and foreach

Tags: php

Hi i've got the following code, I'm trying calculate num rows to show a message if there is no rows in the database. I've got an array and I've used foreach to loop the arrays values and query the database. The problem is that if one of the ids from the array returns 0 rows but the other returns one row I get the value from the database query but also the message saying no rows found. Does anybody know why? Many thanks

```
$user_id = 30;

// Array of ids
$id_gruppo= user_group_ids($conn, $user_id);

$query_last_tickets = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT ticket_id, ticket_subject, ticket_body, ticket_time_stamp, ticket_status, ticket_user_id, ticket_group FROM user_tickets WHERE ticket_group = ? ORDER BY ticket_time_stamp DESC LIMIT 5");   
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query_last_tickets, 'i',  $data);

foreach ($id_gruppo as $data) {

    mysqli_stmt_execute($query_last_tickets);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query_last_tickets, $ticket_id,      $ticketsubject, $ticketbody, $ticketdate, $ticketstatus, $ticketuserid, $ticket_group);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($query_last_tickets);
    $numTicket = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($query_last_tickets);

    if ($numTicket > 0) {

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($query_last_tickets)) {

            echo $ticket_id;

        }

    }   

}

if ($numTicket < 1) {

echo "no rows found";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking the variable `$numTicket` after the loop that is updated inside the loop.

If the last `$numTicket` is 0, you'll fall in your last condition.

You can try something like this :

```
$have_tickets = false ;
foreach ($id_gruppo as $data) {

    mysqli_stmt_execute($query_last_tickets);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query_last_tickets, $ticket_id,      $ticketsubject, $ticketbody, $ticketdate, $ticketstatus, $ticketuserid, $ticket_group);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($query_last_tickets);
    $numTicket = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($query_last_tickets);

    if ($numTicket > 0) {
        $have_tickets = true;
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($query_last_tickets)) {

            echo $ticket_id;

        }

    }   

}

if (!$have_tickets) {
    echo "no rows found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value to `$numTicket` each time through the loop. This means that when you get to the `if` statement after the loop, it will contain the *last* value assigned to it within the loop.  What you want to do is use a flag to determine if *any* of the iterations through the loop produce a count/result.

```
$user_id = 30;

// Array of ids
$id_gruppo= user_group_ids($conn, $user_id);

$query_last_tickets = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT ticket_id, ticket_subject, ticket_body, ticket_time_stamp, ticket_status, ticket_user_id, ticket_group FROM user_tickets WHERE ticket_group = ? ORDER BY ticket_time_stamp DESC LIMIT 5");   
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query_last_tickets, 'i',  $data);

// initialize the flag to false
$ticketsFound = false;

foreach ($id_gruppo as $data) {

    mysqli_stmt_execute($query_last_tickets);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query_last_tickets, $ticket_id,      $ticketsubject, $ticketbody, $ticketdate, $ticketstatus, $ticketuserid, $ticket_group);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($query_last_tickets);
    $numTicket = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($query_last_tickets);

    if ($numTicket > 0) {

        // flip the flag to true since tickets were found
        $ticketsFound = true;

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($query_last_tickets)) {

            echo $ticket_id;

        }

    }   

}

if (!$ticketsFound) {

echo "no rows found";

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but should it not be if($ticketsFound == false) ?

Comment: `!$ticketsFound` is the same as `$ticketsFound == false`